# How to save my barcode scanner result to a text view after scanning

Tags: android, textview, barcode, zxing

My barcode scanner scans the barcode correctly and shows in a message box, however i want it to display in a text view called editTextTag once scanned

```
//barcode scanner
public void scan(View view) {
   zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
   setContentView(zXingScannerView);
   zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
   zXingScannerView.startCamera();

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
   startActivity(new Intent(this,Menu.class));

}


@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  editTextTag.setText(result.getText());

  onPause();

    //this.finish();

}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method `handleResult` is executed from a background thread so try this

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        editTextTag.setText(result.getText());
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry new to this, do i put this inside public void handle result? also no errors but just nothing happens

Comment: No errors again, but still not putting the result in the text view

Comment: Try to put random text in the textView. Maybe the problem is in your layout xml